# Having TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable trouble while programming caesar cipher

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to make caesar cipher program. there's index dictionary made with dictionary data . showing index of letters like `OrderedDict([('A', 0), ('B', 1),...,  ('Y', 24), ('Z', 25)])` and lets say name of dictionary is "Index" so what i want to do is match value of list "dec_i" w dictionary Index's value and the get key value and put in list

```
enc_i = [1, 2, 3, ' ', 4, 5, 6, ' ', 7, 8, 9]
```

RESULT

```
enc_str = ['B', 'C', 'D',' ', 'E', 'F', 'G', ' ', 'H', 'I', 'J']
```

i tried to make it

```
def change():
    j=0
    for a in enc_i:
        for alphabet , number in Index.items():
            if a[j] == ' ':
                enc_str.extend([' '])
            elif number == a[j]:
                    enc_str.append(alphabet)
        j+=1
```

but it doesnt work. saying

> TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

how should i modify or do with my code?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Why not have your `Index` be `OrderedDict([(0, 'A'), (1, 'B'), ...])` so you can look up the values in it?  At the moment you're just treating it like a list of tuples.

Comment: The `if a[j] == ' '` should not be in the `for alphabet, number` loop. That will add 26 spaces to the encoding.

Answer (score 0):

You have confused yourself about your own data types:

```
enc_i = [1, 2, 3, ' ', 4, 5, 6, ' ', 7, 8, 9]

for a in enc_i:
        if a[j] == ' ':
```

`a` is a series of elements from `enc_1`, those being the integers 1 through 9 and two strings of a single blank.  The first three times through your loop, `a` is an integer.  When you hit the error, `a` and `j` are both zero.  Just what do you expect `0[0]` to mean in your `if` statement?

I'm confused.  So is the Python parser.  Confusing the parser gets you an error message.  Remember, the parser makes the rules.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
enc_i = [1, 2, 3, ' ', 4, 5, 6, ' ', 7, 8, 9]
for a in enc_i:
```

a will be 1 in the first iteration, then 2, then 3,... all integers

```
     if a[j] == ' ':
```

integer not subscriptable error, you cant access an index 0 of an integer, it's just a number. You can do enc_i[j] though

```
def change():
    j=0
    for a in enc_i:
        for alphabet , number in Index.items():
            if a == ' ':
                enc_str.extend([' '])
            elif number == a:
                enc_str.append(alphabet)
        j+=1
```

Maybe you want this?